# Running a stream in background with Swing MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, concurrency

I have a `View`, `Model`, `Controller` classes. The `View` and `Model` are passed to the `Controller` constructor and all three are initialized with `EventQueue.invokeLater()` one after another.

The view has a `JList` component. My application requires to run a stream of text lines and to put each line in the `JList` component as they arrive. The stream architecture is done with `Listeners`, so as soon as an element arrives from the stream a `StreamListener` is notified. I need to start or stop the stream.

Now my problem is that I'm not sure how to model such a scenario. Of course setting the Controller as the StreamListener and then using a SwingWorker inside the Controller will solve the problem. However I thought it is the jobs of the Model to handle the streaming and business logic because the role of the Controller is just to facilitate the communications between the `View` and the `Model`.

One way I'm thinking to solve this is by defining a SwingPropertyChangeSupport in the `Model` and let the `Controller` implement `PropertyChangeListener`. Then in the `Model` I create a SwingWorker and call `publish()` every time an element from the stream arrives. Then from `process()` I call `SwingPropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue)` which then will cause the Controller to invoke its implemented method `propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)` which will finally cause the JList to add the element.

However I'm not sure if my approach is correct nor if the code will run on the Event Dispatching Thread. I hope if you can help.

```
public class Model {
    SwingPropertyChangeSupport changeFirer;
    Task task;

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Element> implements StreamListener {
        Stream stream;
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            stream = new Stream();
            stream.start();
        }

        public void onRecieveing(Element element) {
            public(element);
        }

         protected void process(List<Element> elements) {
             Element element = elements.get(elements.size()-1);
             changeFirer.firePropertyChange("updateList", null, element);
     }
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
public class Controller implements PropertyChangeListener {
    Model model;
    View view;
    public Controller(View view, Model model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
        model.setChangeFirer(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Element element = evt.getNewValue();
        view.updateList(element);
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                View view = new View();
                Model model = new Model();
                Controller controller = 
                        new Controller(view, model);
                view.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would agree, it's the responsibility of the model to monitor the state of the of the Stream. Depending on how you "want" to implement it will depend on who re-syncs the updates back to the EDT. For me, unless you document the underlying document to state otherwise, it would be assumed that any updates coming from the model are executed within  the context of the EDT

Answer (score 0):

My solution is correct, propertyChange() runs on EDT and fires correctly.